# How to interactively debug a NodeJS test suite in VS Code?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-debugger

I have a Jest test suite that I would like to debug using the VS Code interactive debugger. That works fine for normal NodeJS programs (`"program": "foo.js"` in `launch.json`). But the test suite (`foo.test.js`) isn't a self-contained program, it has to be run from Jest.

Is there a way to achieve this?

The particular code is here: https://gitlab.com/stevage/guess-projection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Debugging standard Jest tests

[This doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-jest-tests#debugging-tests-in-vs-code) in Microsoft's [vscode-recipies](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes) GitHub repo describes how to set up VS Code for debugging standard Jest tests.

The launch.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest All",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
      "args": ["--runInBand"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "windows": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest Current File",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
      "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "windows": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### Debugging create-react-app Jest tests

If your application is a React app bootstrapped with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) then the configuration is a little different since Jest is not launched directly and is described in [this section](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/debugging-tests#debugging-tests-in-visual-studio-code) of the create-react-app docs.

Comment: Hmm, that first link seems perfect, but it doesn't work for me. VS Code goes into debugging mode, the tests get run...but the breakpoints don't get hit.

Comment: @SteveBennett huh, interesting.  The launch.json from that link is what I've used in the past and I just tried it again with a clean project and seems to work fine in my environment.  Can you share more about your Jest config and environment?

Comment: Added link to my repo. The launch.json is a direct copy from that site. Running on OSX.

Comment: @SteveBennett I just took another look at this.  I cloned your repo and copied in the `launch.json` from the link and was able to hit the breakpoints that I set in both the `Jest Current File` and `Jest All` configs.  I'm running macOS 10.14.2, VSCode 1.30.0, NodeJS 10.14.2.  Did you get it working in your environment?

Comment: No, I didn't manage to get it to work, but glad it did for you. I'm macOS 10.12, VSCode 1.30.0, node 10.0.0.

Comment: Huh, just tested again, it works now. I did do a full computer restart between when I posted this question and now, maybe related to that? Or was perhaps using an older version of node at the time. Either way, awesome, it works now.