# VS Code Mocha debug errors out on ES6 code

Tags: visual-studio-code, mocha.js, jestjs

I'm trying to debug my tests for my React Redux app in VS Code.

Running my tests in Jest works great, but the when I run the debugger I get this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as actions from "../src/redux/actions/tasksActions";
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I'm using the following configuration in my `launch.json`:

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Mocha Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": [
        "--require @babel/register",
        "--inspect-brk",
        "-u",
        "tdd",
        "--timeout",
        "999999",
        "--colors",
        "${workspaceFolder}/tests"
      ],
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }
```

The first args in the config, `"--require @babel/register", "--inspect-brk",` came from suggestions on blogs I found while googling my error (the first arg was said to fix this exact error). Same error happens, though, with or without either of those args.

Here's my `package.json` if it helps.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "expect": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jsdom": "^15.0.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: hmm...is there a reason you're debugging using `mocha` but normally running tests using `jest`?  seems like you should be configuring vscode to debug using `jest`..

Comment: Sounds sensible. And how would I do that?

Comment: This should get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513444/10149510